# Password login program loops forever and displays incorrect results

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a password login program in C++. So there is some mistake in looping.

If the entered password satisfied all the conditions means it had to come out of loop but it doesn't end. So if anyone know means explain me properly. I just have started to learn programming.

Look at the output first. It is showing it must include uppercase and digits and I enter some correct password and when I enter the wrong password knowingly, it is showing that it's good password, which is unexpected for me.

**Here's what I've attempted to do:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int alp = 0, i, num = 0, j;
    char a[10];

    do
    {
        cout << "\nEnter a password:";
        cin >> a;

        if (strlen(a) > 8)
        {
            for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(a); i++)
            {
                if(isupper(a[i]))
                    alp++;
                else if(isdigit(a[i]))
                    num++;
            }
            if (alp > 0 && num > 0)
                cout << "\nGood password\n";
            else
                cout << "Your password must include atleast one digit and one uppercase\n";
        }
        else
            cout << "\nYour password must have atleast 8 characters";
    } while(true);

    return 0;
}
```

**Here's the output:**

```
Enter a password:harry

Your password must have atleast 8 characters
Enter a password:harrypot  

Your password must have atleast 8 characters
Enter a password:harrypott
Your password must include atleast one digit and one uppercase

Enter a password:Harry1817t 

Good password

Enter a password:harrypott

Good password

Enter a password: // forever
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: why do you expect the loop to end? `while(true)` basically means "loop forever"

Comment: A `while(true)` loop without a `break` statement will loop forever.

Comment: While(true) starts an endless loop. Remove it and you are fine.

Comment: `} while (alp == 0 || num == 0);` Also, don't forget to reset `alp = num = 0;` each iteration.

Comment: Note: `cin>>a;` what happens when user enters a string larger than 9 characters? You could use `std::string` or `std::istream::getline()`.

Comment: yeah there may be a chance of that . ok sir i'll think of it.maybe we can use dynamic memory allocation like that. Thank you for responding

Comment: Also, take a look at `for(i = 0; i <= sizeof(a); i++)` -- this should be `for(i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)` otherwise you will be read in uninitialized memory giving you weird results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are several defects in your code:**

1. The `while(true)` is a non-terminating loops, but no `break` is added.
2. The `alp` and `num` weren't reset at the end of the loop iteration.
3. Since the `alp` and `num` weren't reset, they're incremented in each iteration.

**A few notes on the code:**

1. You don't need to include `string.h` or `ctype.h` after `iostream`.
2. In C++, you may use `std::string` class  to manipulate better with strings by using a number of helpful class functions (e.g. if you want to get the string length, then use `variable.length()`, etc.)
3. You shouldn't use:

   ```
   using namespace std;
   ```

   In large programs, they may cause ambiguity. [Why is `using namespace std` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
4. The variable `j` is unused and redundant declaration.

---

**Enhanced version of your code is as follows:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    // important declaration
    std::string password;
    char temp;
    int alpha = 0, digit = 0;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter a password: ";
        std::cin >> password;

        // getting the length
        size_t len = password.length();

        // conditions begins, checks if the password is greater than 8 (9 or more)
        if (!(len > 8)) {
            std::cout << "Password must be greater than 8 chars." << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        // testing each letter
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            temp = password[i];
            // if the char is an alphabet, alpha++
            if (isalpha(temp)) alpha++;

            // or a digit, digit++
            if (isdigit(temp)) digit++;
        }

        // verifying if digit and alpha are greater than 0    
        if (alpha > 0 && digit > 0)
            break;
        else {
            std::cout << "The password must have an alphabetic letter and a digit." << std::endl;
            alpha = digit = 0;
        }
    } while (true);

    // prints when out of loop reaches
    std::cout << "Password was set successful." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Output (sample test cases):**

```
Enter a password: asdf // --------------------------------- < 8 chars
Password must be greater than 8 chars.

Enter a password: safasdfasdfasdf // ---------------------- > 8 chars, but no numeric
The password must have an alphabetic letter and a digit.

Enter a password: 34523523452345 // ----------------------- > 8 chars, but no alpha
The password must have an alphabetic letter and a digit.

Enter a password: asdfa34 // ------------------------------ alpha + numeric, but < 8 chars
Password must be greater than 8 chars.

Enter a password: asfasdfdsaf2 // ------------------------- a good password
Password was set successful.
```

Comment: Thank You bro .In my college they taught me using only "using namespace std".so that i use .But you are using a different technique.std::cout  like that it is new so is there any different in that.

Comment: @SaravananR if you use `using namespace std;` then you don't need to use `std::` anywhere in the code. But in big programs, this will cause ambiguity if a global variable and a local variable or a built-in variable has the same name.

Comment: Thanks for your response bro .so I'm new to stack overflow so if i have any doubts like this can i ask you bro

Comment: Bro ,In this code you have used size_t len= password.length()

Comment: so what is size_t

Comment: is this any default variable or datatype or something .can you explain

Comment: @SaravananR `size_t` means `unsigned long long` and in some systems `unsigned long`. And it's a `typedef` definition and expands to what I mentioned in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You should add "break;" statment to where you want to break the loop after like

```
  if(alp>0 && num>0){
        cout<<"\nGood password\n";
        break;
        }
```

Or add some condition which break the loop

```
       while(i<1){
            if(alp>0 && num>0){
                 cout<<"\nGood password\n";
                 i=2;
                 }
       }
```

Comment: You need to add some `{` and `}` into your answer...

Comment: Thanks for answering sir .I try this

Comment: The answer seems to be incomplete, nowhere mentioned to reset the variables on each iteration to prevent malfunction on next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `break` when the password is good and also bad stuff will happen if the input is bigger than 9 characters, use `std::string` instead of char array something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int alp=0,num=0;
    string a;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter a password:";
        cin>>a;
        if(a.length()>8)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<a.length(); ++i)
            {
                if(isalpha(a[i]))
                {
                        ++alp;
                }
                else if(isdigit(a[i]))
                {
                        ++num;
                }
            }
            if(alp>0 && num>0)
            {
                cout<<"\nGood password\n";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Your password must include atleast one digit and one uppercase\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\nYour password must have atleast 8 characters";
        }
    }while(true);

    return 0;
}
```